# Issue passing back dynamic string array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a form inside a modal popup, The user can enter text in a text box and click a plus button which dynamically adds the text they have typed in to a div so they can then proceed to add another one.

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="prefix">
       Cast <span style="color:red">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-5" id="Cast" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <button type="button" id="btnNewCast" class="btn btn-default">+</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="prefix"></label>
   <div class="col-sm-6" id="newCast">

   </div>
</div>
```

As shown here:

[image]

The NewCast is where I display the entered value by jquery.

When they click btnNewCast the following script is called

```
  $("#btnNewCast").click(function () {
            $("#newCast").append("<span class='label label-success label-as-badge custom-line-height' id='cast[]'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-tag'></i> "+ $("#Cast").val() + "</span><br/>");

            $("#Cast").val('');
        });
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

The HTML is as follows:

```
<span id="cast[]" class="label label-success label-as-badge custom-line-height">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i>
     They Appear Here    
</span>
```

When they press submit on on the form I pass the values back as shown here:

```
 $("#btnAddMovie").click(function() {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Movies/Add',
                    //data: $('NewMovie').serialize(),
                    data: { "Title": $("#Title").val(), "Classification": $("#Classification").val(), "Rating": $("#Rating").val(), "ReleaseDate": $("#ReleaseDate").val(), "Cast": $("#Cast").val() },
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.success) {

                        }
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
        });
```

Which get mapped to my Model, and is working correctly.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Movie model)
    {


        return View();
    }
```

My Model is declared like this:

```
public int MovieId { get; set; }
public int Rating { get; set; }
public int ReleaseDate { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Classification { get; set; }
public string Genre { get; set; }
public string[] Cast { get; set; }
```

The issue I have is as you can see Cast is a string array, the items the user enters (which is shown in the pictures) I'm trying to map them all to the Cast string array when they post.

I have tried

```
"Cast": $("#cast[]").val()
```

But I get a jquery error when posting, unrecognized expression

I can't get it to map correctly..

** Update** Complete post method

```
$("#btnAddMovie").click(function () {

            var stringArr = $('span[data-id="cast[]"]').map(function() {
                return $(this).text().trim();
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Movies/Add',
                //data: $('NewMovie').serialize(),
                data: { "Title": $("#Title").val(), "Classification": $("#Classification").val(), "Rating": $("#Rating").val(), "ReleaseDate": $("#ReleaseDate").val(), "Cast": stringArr },
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {

                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });


        });
```

Comment: @ShaunakD I have an input called Cast that's where they type the names, but the text the users enter gets dynamically added to the view using the jquery I have shown. And I need to pass each entered name back to the controller.  So I need to some how map the names they have entered to the cast string array

Comment: Yes, I was confused when you used `.val()` as `val()` is applicable only to inputs and there wasn't any input in the shown code. See the answer below, check if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues :

1. `<span>` does not have `.val() (value)`, use `text()`.
2. The error

   > Unrecognized expression

   Is because : `[]` - special chars are not allowed in plain `#..` selectors. Use `[id=""]`
3. So use `map()` to iterate over this.

---

```
var stringArr = $('span[id="cast[]"').map(function(){
    return $(this).text().trim();
});
```

Also, the way you are creating `span` through jQuery, the `ID = cast[]` is getting duplicated, and *Duplicated Ids is Invalid markup*. Use class attribute or `data-*` attributes like `data-id="cast[]`. The code would then be :

```
var stringArr = $('span[data-id="cast[]"').map(function(){
    return $(this).text().trim();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yqv5e0pw/)** -

Comment: I have implemented what you had suggest but I now get TypeError: 'assign' called on an object that does not implement interface Location. I have updated my question with the full post method including your suggestion

Comment: Try option `traditional : true,` in ajax http://jsfiddle.net/yqv5e0pw/1/. Or pass a comma separated string and split into array server side.

Comment: that worked, but in my controller instead of getting the text in the Cast[] I get [object, object]

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to use `List<String> Cast` in your model. There are limitations of ajax, where arrays are one.

Comment: I don't have access to the model, its provided by a .dll I have how over looked on the web for converting array to list within a controller and tried the following: List<string> list = new List<string>(model.Cast); this still only shows [object, object]

Comment: Ahh, finally. How did I stupidly missed that map created an object and not array. Please mark the answer as accepted if you wish to.

Comment: @CodeRatchet, any reason why you unaccepted the answer? Just asking :)

Comment: not sure what happened, I did accept it.  either way I've just accepted it again